# Is there any option to change locale in sap.m.Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

sap.ui.commons.DatePicker has a property "locale" to set language of datepicker.But I dont find any property as such in "sap.m.DatePicker" to change the locale.Is there any possible way this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct property for locale in DatePicker. However, there is a somewhat clumsy trick to overcome this, and unfortunately it uses *private* attribute "**_oDisplayFormat**", which stores an instance of **sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat**. The snippet demonstrating this is below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta name="description" content="UI5 DatePicker with non-default locale"/>
 <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge' />
 <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'/>
 
      
      <title>UI5 DatePicker Example with different Locales</title>
 
 <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap' type='text/javascript'
  src='https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js'
  data-sap-ui-theme='sap_bluecrystal'
  data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m,sap.ui.core'>
    </script>

 <script>
      var oVBox = new sap.m.VBox({ width: "50%"});    
      
          var oFrenchFormat;
          var oEnglishFormat;
          
          var oDatePicker = new sap.m.DatePicker({ dateFormat: "long" });
      oDatePicker.setValue(new Date());

      oVBox.addItem(oDatePicker);
          oVBox.addItem(new sap.m.Button({
            text: "Set French locale", 
            press: function(oEvent) {
              if (!oFrenchFormat) {
                oFrenchFormat = sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateInstance({ style: "full"}, new sap.ui.core.Locale("fr_FR"));
              }
              var oDate = oDatePicker.getValue();
              oDatePicker._oDisplayFormat = oFrenchFormat;
              oDatePicker.setDisplayFormat("long");
              oDatePicker.setValue(oDate);
            }
          }));
          
          oVBox.addItem(new sap.m.Button({
            text: "Set US locale", 
            press: function(oEvent) {
              if (!oEnglishFormat) {
                oEnglishFormat = sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateInstance({ style: "full"}, new sap.ui.core.Locale("en_US"));
              }  
              var oDate = oDatePicker.getValue();
              oDatePicker._oDisplayFormat = oEnglishFormat;
              oDatePicker.setDisplayFormat("long");
              oDatePicker.setValue(oDate);
            }
          }));

      oVBox.placeAt("content");
 </script>
 </head>
 <body class="sapUiBody" id="content">
 </body>
</html>
```